# How to create a drop-down list in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have a column of values in Excel, like this :

[image]

How do I turn this into a drop-down list, such at each row in the column will have that drop-down list (with dog, cat , fish, bat , toad. .. all inside )

thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First step is to make a list of the items you want to see in the drop-down, but anywhere in your spreadhseet , like so:

[image]

Then the next step is to click the "Data Validation" button in the ribbon :

[image]

Ok, step 3 is to click "Setitngs" in the "Data Valid" menu , and choose "List" from drop-drown:

[image]

Step 4 is to click on that little blue icon in the "List" sub-menu :

[image]

The next step is to simply highlight the Cells you needs.
[image]

Finished now. Here is dropdown :

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You do that with list validation in the "Data" ribbon.

See [here](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Apply-data-validation-to-cells-c743a24a-bc48-41f1-bd92-95b6aeeb73c9)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the data validation command in the data tools group on the data tab and then select a list and enter a reference to your list (assign it to a name range for simplicity).

Follow this [link](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Insert-or-delete-a-drop-down-list-fdde2fb6-e257-4c62-b794-1427762428c6?ui=en-US&rs=en-NZ&ad=NZ) for complete steps.

Answer (score 0):

To do that, you should use Data Validation as described in [Amit answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31278837/2114786) or in [this page](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/drop-down-list.html) (except that for the seventh point, which I used for my case in Excel 2010, I replaced the ','  with ';')

Answer (score 0):

**Create a hidden drop down list in excel using the Excel data validation options.**

1. Create a list of choice. This option of choice will be appear in drop down list.
    *(I used 4 option of choice from **A1 to A4**, user can increase as per their demand)*

   [image]
2. Select the cell/cells in a column where user wants to appear the drop-down list. I selected the cells in a column D from **D1 to D10**
3. Go to **Data -> Data Validation** page

[image]

4. On Settings page
   A.  In **Allow** field, select the option '**List**'.
    
   B.  Ensure **Ignore blank & In-cell dropdown** option is ticked/selected.
   C.  In the **Source** field, select/enter the range of cells where your original list of choice or your original list of options is present;
   *(here in my case, it’s . $A$1:$A$4)*

   *If you prefer, you can enter this range using the mouse, by clicking on the symbol at the right of the Source field and then selecting the required range of cells with the mouse.*

   D.   Click **OK**.

[image]

5. Once done, select any cell in column D, from **D1 to D10**. Your drop-down menu should appear containing your list of choice values.

   [image]

Now, if you want to hide the column that contains the original list. Right click on column and select **Hide**

Un-Hidding it, by simply typing **A1** in the **Name Box** next to the **formula bar**.

**Reference:**
1. http://www.excelfunctions.net/Excel-Drop-Down-List.html
2. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Show-or-hide-columns-and-rows-659c2cad-802e-44ee-a614-dde8443579f8