# VBA Code to Prevent Users input wrong data into cells Excel

Tags: vba, excel

Hi everyone I am trying to figure out how to write a code where users can only input the exact same data into cells from a list I created. I want the code to validate the user entry and see if the entry is on the list and if is not to erase the data the user enter and give him a message. I am almost there but I don't seem to make my Vlook work. Any help would be very much appreciate it. below is the code I wrote

```
    Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim aCell As Range
    Dim LU As Range
    Dim Celda As Range


'
    On Error GoTo Whoa
    Application.EnableEvents = False
'~~> This is the range of cells where I want the user to input the data
    Set rng = Range("A1:A15")

    'THis is the range where I want the macro to look if the data the user entered is in the list
    Set LU = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(aCell.Value, Range("F1:F5"), 1, False)


On Error GoTo MyErrorHandler:
If Not Application.Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then
        '~~> Loop through all cells in the range
        For Each aCell In rng
            If aCell.Value <> "" Then
                If aCell.Value <> LU Then
                    aCell.ClearContents

MyErrorHandler:
If Err.Number = 1004 Then
aCell.ClearContents
MsgBox "Item Number es Incorrecto - Error en la celda " & aCell.Address

                End If
                End If
            End If
            Next
        End If


Letscontinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Letscontinue


End Sub
```

Comment: Any reason why you are using VBA when data validation can do this exactly?

Comment: Why aren't you using a validation list? http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal01.html

Comment: @nbayly 15 seconds faster xD

Comment: @RCaetano lol, I hate when that happens too ;p

Comment: Maybe you should check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31279376/6671476

Comment: I don't want to use Data Validation because user can do a Copy Paste and erase the Data Validation. Also the list I want to be validated has hundreds of options making it difficult to use Data Validation as they will need to scroll down from the list an choose

Answer (score 0):

Use Data - Data Validation, set to Allow by List. For source place `=$F$1:$F$5`. Customize options to your needs. No VBA needed.

Comment: I don't want to use Data Validation because user can do a Copy Paste and erase the Data Validation. Also the list I want to be validated has hundreds of options making it difficult to use Data Validation as they will need to scroll down from the list an choose

Comment: Your right, the copy and paste will not trigger the data validation. The part about scrolling down I don't think is necessarily true as they can type the value in as well. As long as it matches one of the options it will not error. As a thought you could combine VBA with DV, triggering an event on change, checking if Paste was the last action from the undo list and finding a way to trigger the data validation through VBA maybe by resetting the value to the cell.

Comment: Thanks nbayly thats kind of what I am trying to achieve with my code above, I tested it with once cell and it works fine, the problem I am encountering is when I use the VLookup to find a product in the range. Any idea of why is not working? I get an error message "Object Variable or with block variable not set"  I tried everything but I can't figure out what it is

Comment: That sounds like you haven't scoped your range inside the formula. Try adding `Set LU = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(aCell.Value, ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("F1:F5"), 1, False)` and let me know if you get an error.

Comment: Actually I don't see where you set `aCell`'s range before doing the vlookup. That seems more likely the root of your error. I think maybe you should place the vlookup inside your loop as this is where you set a rotating value for `aCell`. You could also just pull the range with your validation list into an array and loop through there rather than using vlookup.

Comment: I found the solution to prevent users from pasting data that doesn't match to that on a list. The only problem I have now is that it takes a long time and also sometimes it doesn't work. Does anyone have any suggestions of how to improve this code??? Below  is the code I wrote and that it worked.